# loop an activity with questions and buttons

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to build a questionnaire so I build a question page with many buttons to check. Then, I have an OK button to store the results. And then I want to come back to the same page to answer again the questions for someone else.

Actually, I need to do:

```
public void onStop(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // relaunch the same activity
}
```

I tried to build a infinite loop (while true {} do;)
But, it does not wait for the

```
OK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {}}
```

Any idea on how to loop on that activity ?

Comment: if you have a list of questions, use ListView to display them, the other part about reopen activity is not clear at all

Comment: Basically, it is muliple choice questionnaire : it is the same list of questions to answer with spinners or radiobutton on 1 sheet that I want to repeat after clicking OK and registering the answers.

Comment: On API level 11+ you can call `recreate()` in your buttons on click listener (after you store the results).